Track data using a digital elevation model (DEM) shows bridges and tunnels as "outliers"
(cross post from Stackoverflow)
I've recorded bike tracks with very noisy results for altitude (barometric sensor). I enhanced the altitude data using a digital elevation model. See example here:

However, crossing bridges or tunnels introduces "outliers" that do not accurately reflect the actual profile of the ride. Is there any way to remove these outliers? I aim to achieve a result similar to the red lines in the picture below:

Raw data:
distance,altitude
0.0,142.27000427246094
0.0,142.27000427246094
0.0,142.27000427246094

Full data here: https://pastebin.com/Tf1vxFNT

Sounds like a job for a median filter-based anomaly detector followed by linear interpolation: essentially, you slide a "window" of some defined length (widest bridge) over your signal, calculate the median value of that window, and when there's values that deviate drastically, you mark them as invalid. Afterwards, you interpolate invalid values from their neighbors.
You might need to extend that scheme: you find the first point that leaves the acceptance range, then assume you're on a bridge until you a shorter, new median filter says you've made an upwards jump.

That was a great suggestion! I implemented the first part and it already works great.
